# Passing rvalue to function that may not use it

Tags: c++, c++11

Lets say I have a class defined as follows:

```
class Foo {
public:
    ...
    bool add_widget(Widget&& w) {
        if (some condition) {
            return false;
        }

        container.push_back(std::move(w));
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::deque<Widget> container;
}
```

and I call the class as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo f;
    Widget w;

    if (!f.add_widget(std::move(w))) {
        // Can I still use w here?
    }
}
```

If `some condition` is true, the Widget `w` will not be added to Foo's `container`. In `main()`, when `add_widget()` returns indicating that the add was not successful, can I still use `w`, or should I always assume it has been moved and is no longer usable?

Is it bad practice to write a function like `add_widget()` that takes an r-value reference but may not actually move it's argument?

Comment: I'd be afraid that one day someone would come and change the signature of `add_widget` into `bool add_widget(Widget w)`, so I perceive this style as bad practice

Comment: IMHO if a client `std::move`'s a value into a function, they should assume that the object has been moved out from under them, even if that's not always the case (client shouldn't necessarily care about the implementation of the function, only the preconditions and postconditions). It's not necessarily bad practice to write it as you have; it all depends on your use case.  There are times when Piotr's solution is better, and times when yours is.

Comment: The code is technically fine, though it perhaps violates the standard guidance that a value bound to an rvalue reference has no aliases. An alternative that doesn't suffer from this problem would be to take an lvalue reference and perform the move inside the function.

Comment: Regarding good/bad practice: if it is not expected to be part of normal behaviour for `add_widget` to fail, then throwing an exception is good practice. It keeps your code clean because you don't have to wrap everything in `if` tests.  If it is normal for `add_widget` to fail then perhaps the function should indicate that in its filename, e.g. one convention is that `foo()` throws, and `tryFoo()` returns a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "some condition" evaluates to `true` then the `add_widget` member function will return before the input `w` is moved in `deque`. Thus, you can use `w` in main safely.

Have in mind that `std::move` doesn't actually move an object. `std::move` is nothing more than a type cast.

Even if `w` was moved then `w` in main would have been in a valid but unspecified state.

Meaning that you could perform any operation on `w` which would have no preconditions. If there's an operation with preconditions you would like to perform, then you would have to perform that operation indirectly, because you wouldn't know if the unspecified-state of the object satisfies the preconditions.

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c5c71cc9ab45234)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to use widget in that case, as its state is not altered in any way.

However, you should only rely on this behavior, if you explicitly document it in the function description and - as a result - are willing to commit to that guarantee even in case of future refactoring.

One could argue, whether or not this is too clever and/or surprising, but in fact it is not too different from relying on the strong exception guarantee of functions like `std::vector::push_back()`.

Answer (score 0):

This idiom is used in the standard library as of c++17.

Have a look at the second form of `std::map::try_emplace`

reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace

Note that the key type (and indeed in some cases, the arguments used to construct the value) are r-value references, but they are only moved into the map if the key is not already present.